# ComboBoxのSelectedIndexを、C#側で設定する方法をお願いします。

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

`ComboBox`をC#側で作成するとき、`SelectedIndex`プロパティの設定方法がわかりません。
どのようなメソッドを使えばよいのでしょうか？

以下のxamlを例に、回答をお願いします。

```
<ComboBox Name="newCombo"
            SelectedIndex="{
　　　　　　　　Binding someData, 
　　　　　　　　Mode=TwoWay, 
　　　　　　　　UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ComboBoxItem>A</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>B</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

現在、自分がこれまで考えたC#のコードは、以下となります。

```
var cmb = 
    new ComboBox() {
        Name = "newCombo",
        SelectedIndex = someData,
    };

var binding = 
    new Binding
    {
        Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
        UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
    };

// ここから自分はわかりません。
// cmbに、何からの方法でbindingを組み込むのか、
// 或いは、別の方法か？
```

Answer (score 3):

cmbにSetBindingでbindingを組み込むことができます。
例: `cmb.SetBinding(ComboBox.SelectedIndexProperty, binding);`

下記のサンプルコードはWpfApp1プロジェクトで動的に作成したコンボボックスのSelectedIndexとテキストボックスのTextを連動させています。

**サンプルコード**

*MainWindow.xaml.cs*

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        MySelection mySelection;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            mySelection = new MySelection();
            // バインディング作成
            var binding = new Binding("SelectedIndex")
            {
                Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
                UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged,
                Source = mySelection,
            };
            // 動的コンボボックス作成
            var cmb = new ComboBox
            {
                Name = "newCombo",
                ItemsSource = new List<string> { "A", "B" },
            };

            // ☆ バインディングをコンボボックスのSelectedInexに設定する ☆
            cmb.SetBinding(ComboBox.SelectedIndexProperty, binding);

            // C#側で動的に作成したコンボボックスとテキストボックスを配置
            var grid = (Content as Grid);
            grid.Children.Add(cmb);
            var text = new TextBox();
            text.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
            Grid.SetColumn(text, 2);
            grid.Children.Add(text);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 変更通知用クラス(C# 6.0 以降で使用可)
    /// </summary>
    public class MySelection : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int selectedIndex;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
        public int SelectedIndex
        {
            get { return selectedIndex; }
            set
            {
                selectedIndex = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedIndex");
            }
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? info = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
```

*MainWindow.xaml*

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="SelectedIndexと右のテキストは連動する"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございました。
とても役に立ちました。
なかなか調べてもネット検索に引掛かからないので、非常に困惑していていた中でしたので、とても安心しました。